# background fetching causes app freeze than foreground fetching

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have implemented background fetching in coredata, but it still getting app freeze few seconds than normal fetching. Is there any thing i can do for fast fetching?Seems that it still fetching on foreground,don't know what is wrong with code.

```
- (void)sr_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request completion:(void (^)(NSArray *objects, NSError *error))completion {

NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [sharedDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

[backgroundContext performBlock:^{

    // Fetch into shared persistent store in background thread
    NSError *error = nil;
    //        NSLog(@"BG thread===== ");

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [context performBlock:^{
        if (fetchedObjects) {
            // Collect object IDs
            NSMutableArray *mutObjectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[fetchedObjects count]];
            for (NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects) {
                [mutObjectIds addObject:obj.objectID];
    //                    NSLog(@"BG bg===== ");

            }

            // Fault in objects into current context by object ID as they are available in the shared persistent store
            NSMutableArray *mutObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[mutObjectIds count]];
            for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in mutObjectIds) {
                NSManagedObject *obj = [context objectWithID:objectID];
                [mutObjects addObject:obj];
   //                    NSLog(@"BG fg===== ");

            }

            if (completion) {
                NSArray *objects = [mutObjects copy];
                completion(objects, nil);
            }
        } else {
            if (completion) {
                completion(nil, error);
            }
        }
    }];
}];
}
```

I have some records in server, when background to foreground the app server will send all the records and from client side i'm savings all data into coredata. While saving i need to check whether those data are already exist or not,and sometimes i need to fetch some data from db before save, but in these time my app became frozen, and its working fine only after all updates and savings are done.

Profiler trace https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b1gykvs1pezrcp/Instruments4.trace.zip?dl=0

**SAVE to DB**

```
     -(void)updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)inDictionary
  {

 NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

 AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

  //    NSManagedObjectContext *writerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
  //   [writerContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[sharedDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
 ////    
  ////    // create main thread MOC
 //    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]        initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    //    context.parentContext = writerContext;
  ////

NSManagedObjectContext *contextforThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

contextforThread.parentContext = context;

[contextforThread performBlock:^{




NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",loginUser];
NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"threadID == %@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[userPredicate, threadPredicate]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
for (ThreadInfo *threadInfo in fetchedObjects)
{
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"badgeValue"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.badgeValue=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"thread"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"key"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"key"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadKey=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"key"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"secret_seed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"secret_seed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadSecret=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"secret_seed"]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"r_key"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_key"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.remoteKey=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_key"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitation"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"r_secret"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_secret"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.remoteSecret=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_secret"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"icon_idx"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_idx"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.avatarIconIndex=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_idx"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"icon_color_idx"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_color_idx"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.avatarColorIndex=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_color_idx"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"encrypted_r_secret"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"encrypted_r_secret"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.encryptedRemoteSecret=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"encrypted_r_secret"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isSystemMessage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSystemMessage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isSystemMessage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSystemMessage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"ref"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"ref"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.systemReferenceURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"ref"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"url"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"url"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.systemMessageURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"url"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"thumbnailImageURL"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"thumbnailImageURL"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.thumbnailImageURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thumbnailImageURL"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"from"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"from"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receiverEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"from"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isQuiz"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isQuiz"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isQuiz=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isQuiz"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"replied"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"replied"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.replied=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"replied"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"owned"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"owned"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            BOOL isOwner=[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"owned"] boolValue];
            if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitation"])
            {
                if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"]!=[NSNull null])
                {

                    if(isOwner)
                    {

                        if ([[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"] isEqualToString:[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]])
                        {
                            threadInfo.isRequester=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        } else {
                            threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //                            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        if ([[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"] isEqualToString:[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]])
                        {
                            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        } else {
                            threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isOwner)
                    {
                        threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(isOwner)
                {
                    threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                }
                else
                {
                    threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                }
            }


        }

    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"options"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"options"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            NSMutableArray *accArray=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"options"];
            NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accArray];
            threadInfo.pollOptions = arrayData;
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isAnyReceiverActivity=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"pollAnswerList"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"pollAnswerList"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *accDict=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"pollAnswerList"];
            NSData *dictData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accDict];
            threadInfo.pollAnswerList = dictData;
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"responseCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"responseCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.responseCount=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"responseCount"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isSender"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSender"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSender"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isRequester"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isRequester"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isRequester=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isRequester"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"image"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"image"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
             threadInfo.image=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"image"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isReceiver"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isReceiver"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isReceiver"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"colorCode"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"colorCode"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.colorCode=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"colorCode"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitationCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationCount=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationCount"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitationNumber"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationNumber"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationNumber=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationNumber"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"disliked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"disliked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasDislikes=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"disliked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"liked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"liked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasLikes=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"liked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"removed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"removed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadRemoved=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"removed"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"closed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"closed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadEnded=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"closed"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"blocked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"blocked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadBlocked=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"blocked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"hasComments"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"hasComments"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasComments=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"hasComments"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isProvider"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isProvider"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isProvider"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"messageDescription"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"messageDescription"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.messageDescription=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"messageDescription"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"commentCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"commentCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.commentCount=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"commentCount"] integerValue]];
        }

    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"threadDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDate"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"receivedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"receivedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receivedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"receivedDate"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"closedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"closedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.closedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"closedDate"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"blockedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"blockedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.blockedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"blockedDate"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"threadDescription"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDescription"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadMessage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDescription"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"receiverEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"receiverEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receiverEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"receiverEmail"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"to"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"to"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            id toValue=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"to"];
            if([toValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                if ([toValue rangeOfString:@"@"].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    threadInfo.receiverEmail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",toValue];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSMutableArray *accArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:toValue];
                NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accArray];
                threadInfo.solicitationList = arrayData;
            }

        }

    }
    //Poll
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isPoll"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPoll"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isPoll=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPoll"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"type"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"type"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollType=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"type"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"scope"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"scope"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollScope=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"scope"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isPollSender"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPollSender"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isPollSender=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPollSender"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"visibility"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"visibility"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollVisibility=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"visibility"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"yesPercentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"yesPercentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.yesPercentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"yesPercentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"noPercentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"noPercentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.noPercentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"noPercentage"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"selectedOption"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedOption"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.selectedOption=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedOption"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"selectedStar"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedStar"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.selectedStar=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedStar"];
        }
    }

            if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice1Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice1Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice2Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice2Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice3Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice3Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice4Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice4Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice5Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice5Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"];
        }
    }

 }

    NSError *error;
    if(![contextforThread save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Child error : %@",error);

    }

    [context performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
               }];
}];


 }
```

**websocket** // Data getting from server continuesly

```
 - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
  {
           NSDictionary *responseDict = [message JSONValue];
     NSArray *bodyDicta=[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"];
                for (int i=0; i<bodyDicta.count; i++) {
                    int responseCode=[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];


                    [self checkResponseCode:[bodyDicta objectAtIndex: i] indexvalue:responseCode isArray:1];
 }
```

**checkResponseCode**

```
  -(void)checkResponseCode:(NSDictionary *)responseDict indexvalue:(int)code isArray:(int)flag {

   if(code==3608)
   {
    [self manageGroupDetails:responseDict];
    }

  if (code == 3602)// SCROLL ISSUE
   {

    [self updateThreadWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
   }
   if (code == 3603)
   {

    [self updateCommentWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
   }
   if(code==3607)// SCROLL ISSUE
  {
    [self updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
  }
}
```

**updatePollWithSyncDetails**

```
-(void)updatePollWithSyncDetails:(NSDictionary *)responseDict
 {
     BOOL isDuplicate=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] checkForExistenceOfThreadDetailsForThreadID:[responseDict objectForKey:@"poll"]];
if(!isDuplicate)
{
             [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:detailsDict];
 }
```

**updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails**

```
 -(void)updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:(NSDictionary *)inDictionary
 {
 NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:inDictionary];
 NSString *userEmail=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];
[paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSystemMessage"];                          
                [paramDict setObject:message forKey:@"threadDescription"];
                ThreadInfo *threadInfo=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] retrieveSolicitationInfoForThreadID:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"solicitation"]];
                [paramDict setObject:threadInfo.threadID forKey:@"thread"];
                [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:paramDict];
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Using the xCode debugger, you can add a breakpoint inside the blocks and check which thread they are executing in.

Comment: yes they are executing, I have already NSlogged the value. Is there any thing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost, how do you know it is the fetch blocking your UI?  Have you run Instruments on this?  If so, where is the trace?

If you have not then you need to stop, run Instruments, use the Time Profiler and find the block.  Update your question with a link to the trace so it can be downloaded and reviewed.

Without looking at this issue in Instruments you are only guessing and what the actual issue is.

### Update 1

Looking at the trace you provided I do not see Core Data taking up any significant amount of time on the main thread (or any other thread).  I suspect you are chasing the wrong thing here.

Your code above does not save you any time.  While it will load objects into the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to make it slightly faster for your main `NSManagedObjectContext` to fetch them it is insignificant.  Based on your time trace you are not spending any time in SQL (132ms total on the main thread).

Even if your SQL call took a significant amount of time it would **still** block the main thread because you are locking the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` when you perform your fetch.

Based on the trace you provided, your issue is in your UI.  The bulk of your time is spent in `-[IXInBoxViewController tableView;heightForRowAtIndexPath:]` which is a common place to lock the UI.  Drill into your profile, find the expensive item and fix it.

The issue is not Core Data.  I would suggest removing this threading code (adding threading is not a performance solution) and go back to using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with your `UITableViewController` then profile your UI code and fix the slow code.

### Update 2

> I'm getting large amount of data from server and savings to core data continuously. . I'm using NSFetchedResultsController, So for every savings tableview must be reloaded. Now I'm trying to save small amount of data at at time, Is this the correct way to handle large number of save request to core data?

You did not present any code for loading the data or saving the data so I can't speak with authority whether or not you are doing those parts right.

The amount of data you load does not matter as long as it is loaded on a background context on a background thread (I prefer to use NSOperation subclasses) and saved into Core Data.  The `NSFetchedResultsController` will do the right thing and UI impact will be minimal unless you are simultaneously displaying the data.  If the data is loading into the `NSFetchedResultsController` and it is relatively off screen then it will not have a major impact on performance.

Run Instruments.  That is your first step whenever performance is a question.

If your data loading is slow, isolate the lines that are slow and address them.

If your save is slow (unlikely) then break it into smaller pieces.

But profile it first.  Otherwise you are shooting in the dark and just guessing.

Comment: ok sir, but i found this issue by  commenting those methods which calls for saving and fetching coredata. after that it works fine,

Comment: Sir, i have updated my question with the exact issue

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try to fix the UI issues. I'm getting large amount of data from server and savings to core data continuously. . I'm using NSFetchedResultsController, So for every savings tableview must be reloaded. Now I'm trying to save small amount of data at at time, Is this the correct way to handle large number of save request to core data?

Comment: Please move that into a separate question and close this one.

Comment: ok, sir, I have opened another link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959032/while-saving-to-core-data-app-getting-frozen-for-few-seconds

Answer (score 1):

You have your line of code...

```
backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
```

...within the block.

Try setting the PSC for your MOC before you commence the `performBlock`.

Comment: Actually this fetching is done in background thread then why the main thread blocking? Im so confused. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Apologies didn't notice this before, but you have you main `context` wrapped up in the `performBlock` method of your `backgroundContent`. This will block your UI

Comment: I got this method by reference. my problem is fetching blocks my UI, Thats why i used background fetching, I don't know if there is another method for that. can you help me? Really stuck at this point.