# While saving to core data app getting frozen for few seconds

Tags: ios, core-data

I have some records in server, when background to foreground the app server will send all the records and from client side i'm savings all data into coredata. While saving i need to check whether those data are already exist or not,and sometimes i need to fetch some data from db before save, but in these time my app became frozen, and its working fine only after all updates and savings are done.

profiler: https://www.dropbox.com/s/epw1939vxakxt7k/Instruments5.trace.zip?dl=0

**SAVE to DB**

```
     -(void)updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)inDictionary
  {

 NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

 AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

  //    NSManagedObjectContext *writerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
  //   [writerContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[sharedDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
 ////    
  ////    // create main thread MOC
 //    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]        initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    //    context.parentContext = writerContext;
  ////

NSManagedObjectContext *contextforThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

contextforThread.parentContext = context;

[contextforThread performBlock:^{




NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",loginUser];
NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"threadID == %@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[userPredicate, threadPredicate]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
for (ThreadInfo *threadInfo in fetchedObjects)
{
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"badgeValue"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.badgeValue=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"thread"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"key"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"key"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadKey=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"key"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"secret_seed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"secret_seed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadSecret=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"secret_seed"]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"r_key"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_key"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.remoteKey=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_key"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitation"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"r_secret"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_secret"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.remoteSecret=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"r_secret"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"icon_idx"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_idx"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.avatarIconIndex=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_idx"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"icon_color_idx"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_color_idx"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.avatarColorIndex=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"icon_color_idx"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"encrypted_r_secret"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"encrypted_r_secret"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.encryptedRemoteSecret=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"encrypted_r_secret"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isSystemMessage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSystemMessage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isSystemMessage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSystemMessage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"ref"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"ref"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.systemReferenceURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"ref"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"url"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"url"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.systemMessageURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"url"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"thumbnailImageURL"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"thumbnailImageURL"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.thumbnailImageURL=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thumbnailImageURL"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"from"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"from"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receiverEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"from"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isQuiz"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isQuiz"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isQuiz=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isQuiz"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"replied"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"replied"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.replied=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"replied"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"owned"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"owned"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            BOOL isOwner=[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"owned"] boolValue];
            if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitation"])
            {
                if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"]!=[NSNull null])
                {

                    if(isOwner)
                    {

                        if ([[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"] isEqualToString:[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]])
                        {
                            threadInfo.isRequester=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        } else {
                            threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //                            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        if ([[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitation"] isEqualToString:[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]])
                        {
                            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        } else {
                            threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isOwner)
                    {
                        threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(isOwner)
                {
                    threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                }
                else
                {
                    threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

                }
            }


        }

    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"options"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"options"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            NSMutableArray *accArray=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"options"];
            NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accArray];
            threadInfo.pollOptions = arrayData;
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isAnyReceiverActivity=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isAnyReceiverActivity"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"pollAnswerList"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"pollAnswerList"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *accDict=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"pollAnswerList"];
            NSData *dictData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accDict];
            threadInfo.pollAnswerList = dictData;
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"responseCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"responseCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.responseCount=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"responseCount"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isSender"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSender"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isSender=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isSender"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isRequester"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isRequester"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isRequester=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isRequester"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"image"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"image"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
             threadInfo.image=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"image"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isReceiver"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isReceiver"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isReceiver=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isReceiver"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"colorCode"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"colorCode"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.colorCode=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"colorCode"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitationCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationCount=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationCount"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"solicitationNumber"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationNumber"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.solicitationNumber=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"solicitationNumber"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"disliked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"disliked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasDislikes=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"disliked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"liked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"liked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasLikes=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"liked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"removed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"removed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadRemoved=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"removed"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"closed"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"closed"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadEnded=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"closed"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"blocked"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"blocked"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isThreadBlocked=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"blocked"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"hasComments"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"hasComments"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.hasComments=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"hasComments"] boolValue]];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isProvider"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isProvider"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isProvider=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isProvider"] boolValue]];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"messageDescription"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"messageDescription"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.messageDescription=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"messageDescription"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"commentCount"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"commentCount"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.commentCount=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"commentCount"] integerValue]];
        }

    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"threadDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDate"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"receivedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"receivedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receivedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"receivedDate"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"closedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"closedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.closedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"closedDate"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"blockedDate"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"blockedDate"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.blockedDate=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"blockedDate"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"threadDescription"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDescription"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadMessage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"threadDescription"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"receiverEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"receiverEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.receiverEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"receiverEmail"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"to"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"to"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            id toValue=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"to"];
            if([toValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                if ([toValue rangeOfString:@"@"].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    threadInfo.receiverEmail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",toValue];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSMutableArray *accArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:toValue];
                NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accArray];
                threadInfo.solicitationList = arrayData;
            }

        }

    }
    //Poll
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isPoll"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPoll"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isPoll=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPoll"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"type"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"type"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollType=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"type"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"scope"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"scope"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollScope=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"scope"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"isPollSender"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPollSender"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.isPollSender=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"isPollSender"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"visibility"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"visibility"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.pollVisibility=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"visibility"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"yesPercentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"yesPercentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.yesPercentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"yesPercentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"noPercentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"noPercentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.noPercentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"noPercentage"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"selectedOption"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedOption"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.selectedOption=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedOption"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"selectedStar"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedStar"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.selectedStar=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"selectedStar"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice1Value"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Value"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice1Value=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Value"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice2Value"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Value"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice2Value=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Value"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice3Value"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Value"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice3Value=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Value"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice4Value"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Value"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice4Value=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Value"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice5Value"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Value"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice5Value=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Value"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice1Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice1Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice1Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice2Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice2Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice2Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice3Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice3Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice3Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice4Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice4Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice5Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice5Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"];
        }
    }


 }




    NSError *error;
    if(![contextforThread save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Child error : %@",error);

    }

    [context performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }

               }];
}];


 }
```

**websocket** // Data getting from server continuesly

```
 - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
  {
           NSDictionary *responseDict = [message JSONValue];
     NSArray *bodyDicta=[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"];
                for (int i=0; i<bodyDicta.count; i++) {
                    int responseCode=[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"body"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];


                    [self checkResponseCode:[bodyDicta objectAtIndex: i] indexvalue:responseCode isArray:1];
 }
```

**checkResponseCode**

```
  -(void)checkResponseCode:(NSDictionary *)responseDict indexvalue:(int)code isArray:(int)flag {

   if(code==3608)
   {
    [self manageGroupDetails:responseDict];
    }

  if (code == 3602)// SCROLL ISSUE
   {

    [self updateThreadWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
   }
   if (code == 3603)
   {

    [self updateCommentWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
   }
   if(code==3607)// SCROLL ISSUE
  {
    [self updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:responseDict];
  }
}
```

**updatePollWithSyncDetails**

```
-(void)updatePollWithSyncDetails:(NSDictionary *)responseDict
 {
     BOOL isDuplicate=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] checkForExistenceOfThreadDetailsForThreadID:[responseDict objectForKey:@"poll"]];
if(!isDuplicate)
{
             [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:detailsDict];
 }
```

**updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails**

```
 -(void)updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:(NSDictionary *)inDictionary
 {
 NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:inDictionary];
 NSString *userEmail=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];
[paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSystemMessage"];                          
                [paramDict setObject:message forKey:@"threadDescription"];
                ThreadInfo *threadInfo=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] retrieveSolicitationInfoForThreadID:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"solicitation"]];
                [paramDict setObject:threadInfo.threadID forKey:@"thread"];
                [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:paramDict];
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the Instruments trace that you attached to this question?  If you:

1. separate the call tree by thread
2. invert the call tree
3. hide system libraries

You will see that all of your work is being done on the main thread and that most of the time is being spent in:

- `-[IXWebSocketDataManager webSocket: didReceiveMessage:]`
- `-[IXWebSocketDataManager checkResponseCode: indexvalue: isArray:]`
- `-[IXWebSocketDataManager updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:]`

None of which should be on the Main thread.

The main thread is for User Interface updates **ONLY**.  All of your data processing should be running in the background, either in a `NSOperation` subclass or a GCD block or something.  Get that data processing off the main thread and your performance will improve.

Whatever you are using to retrieve the data from the network is returning on the main thread.  That seems to be the source of this problem.

Comment: But sir, except -[IXWebSocketDataManager webSocket: didReceiveMessage:] the other two methods make a call to SAVE coredata  , So whenever we tried to include these methods in GCD app becomes more deadlock,

Comment: Best part of this answer is how to read Instruments trace! You could add this kind of debugging into your next CoreData speech :)

Comment: It will most likely be covered in my next Workshop :)

Comment: @MuhsinaMuhammed: If you open up a fresh trace on your work machine and double click on each of those lines you will go into the code view and you will see **exactly** which line is taking the most time.  If you want to solve performance problems it is **vital** that you learn how to use Instruments.